# How do i change the background colour on this html5up template?

Tags: html, css, background

I want to change the brown colour that is the background but I cant seem to change it, no matter how many colors i change in the css file.. i have changed all the places where colour is entered, backgroundcolor, but nothing changes.. please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try it by adding `!important` i.e

```css
background-color: red !important;
```

Answer (score 0):

since you have not provided the css code, we cannot help you precisely.

Try adding the following code to the CSS file:

```css
body, #root {
  background-color: #964b00;
}
```

> `<body>` tag defines the document's body.

> `:root` selector matches the document's root element.

> `background-color` property sets the background color of an element.
> In this case it sets the background of **body** tag and **:root** selector to **#964b00** *(brown)*. That should result in the background being brown.

If it doesn't help, please provide the CSS code so we can investigate the issue further...